# Compile & link with SWIG on mac that will run on windows

Tags: c++, python, macos, windows-xp, swig

I have a python program that uses a bit of c++ code that I used SWIG to compile and link. I compiled the c++ code with swig under mac osx. I would like to give the python program to someone who uses windows xp. Is there a way to compile the c++ on the mac so that it will run on windows? Here is the code I used to compile and link the mac version.

```
swig -classic -c++ -python pythoncpp.i
g++ -O2 -c -arch i386 -fPIC  pythoncpp.cpp -I/path  -I/path
g++ -O2 -c -arch i386 -fPIC  pythoncpp_wrap.cxx -I/path  -I/path -L/path
ld -bundle -flat_namespace -undefined suppress -L/path -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm -o _pythoncpp.so *.o
```

Comment: This isn't really related to SWIG or Python. What you need to figure out is how to get g++ to cross-compile to target Windows on a Mac.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into g++ cross compiling.